# Access 2013 Run-time error '2683': There is no object in this control

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

New member, new to coding, so let's pretend I know nothing.  I have perused other postings, but haven't been able to solve my issue.  We updated our operating system recently and the Access 2013 version does not seem to jive with a data entry form programmed by a previous employee.  When I click on a date icon to populate a datepicker function, I get a Run-time error '2683'.  When I proceed to debug, the code reads...

```
Private Sub Command5_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCal"
[Forms]![frmCal]![frCal].Value = Now()
End Sub
```

And the second line is highlighted yellow.  I would greatly appreciate any help solving this so I can easily select dates from a calendar pop-up.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure, but from what I have read...possibly?  I can provide more of the code if needed...

Comment: Private Sub Command1_Click()
[Forms]![frmMasterEntry]![sdate] = frCal.Value
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmCal"
[Forms]![frmMasterEntry]![sdate].SetFocus
End Sub

Comment: Here is the code in the Design View.  Does this make any sense...?  Like I said, I'm a novice.

Comment: I have the property sheet open now...

Comment: I'm certainly getting somewhere using the built-in DatePicker.  I can get it to populate in my form, but I don't know how to have it transfer my date selection to the next form, which allows me to enter specific data for each week day.

Comment: Sorry if I got you confused. In the original posting, I described the run-time error occurring when I select the date icon (circled in red). The date icon used to trigger a pop-up form where I could select a date (Mondays) and that form would then populate the next form where I could enter data relating to what work was done on each workday. So, I thought the run-time error was due to the date pop-up... does this make sense?

Comment: The debug window showed that the second line of code was highlighted yellow.

Comment: [Forms]![frmCal]![frCal].Value = Now()

Comment: I don't know what frmCal in the code means or frCal that you mentioned...

Comment: I do, but I do not know how to share on here...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1whnM4xzbNzMUpXRklQRzQ0SUU/view?usp=sharing